# CGI script to connect to unix host and trigger perl script and report back the status

Tags: perl, cgi

I need some heads up here. I need to write a CGI script which has to connect unix host and execute set of perl scripts.
I am new to CGI world and I have couple of questions in my mind for which I don't know perl solution.

1. How will connect to Unix host from CGI script. I believe using `Net::SSH` ,is there any better module to do this ?
2. Lets assume I have connected to the server , now how would I execute the script and how would I now the status (running/success/failure)
   of the script.

   a. When its running I would like to see the output that gets generated. Is it possible to view the script output in realtime?

   b. If its a failure then I should be notified and reason for failure and should not trigger the next script in sequence.

If someone has similar setup already available and ready to show the code/setup , I would be much happier :)

Comment: Here's how I learned it http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.60/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm

Comment: there are few times , where my script will exit with signal 1 , but just on that occasion i don't want `Net::OpenSSH` to redirect it to the error variable. is that possible ? also i see my user profile does not get loaded. So i do something like `.profile && my_perl_script.pl` while executing it remotely using ssh ?